# R Shiny app 'error: Failed to parse C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp672zUi/file2cb4f1a71c0: Invalid file, or file has unsupported features.'

Tags: r, shiny

I tried to create an R shiny app, to see the data from the file location, used the fileinput widget as per the code to read two different data types one in .rds and another in .sas7bdat (SAS). all is well i am able to select the type of file from the browse and view the dataset, however once i select the data type and file and move to select another data type it shows an error message when i toggle between the data types eventually i see the data both ways, but its the error message i want to remove when i toggle between the data types.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
library(admiral.test)
library(haven)
library(coler)
setwd('E:\\R')
path <- getwd()
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('To select different types of data file and view there contents'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons('dataset','Select the data file', c(Rdataset='rda', SAS='sas7bdat')),
                   fileInput('filepath', 'File path to select the dataset',accept = '.rda')
      
    ), 
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('table'),
      tableOutput('table2')
    )
  )
)


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$table <- renderTable({
     if (is.null(input$filepath)) {
       return()
     } else {
       input$filepath
     }
   })
   
   table2 <- reactive({
     if (is.null(input$filepath)) {return()}
     if (!is.null(input$filepath)) {
      if (input$dataset=='rda'){
       filepath2 <- input$filepath
       filepath3 <- filepath2$datapath
       rda <- readRDS(filepath3)
       #saveRDS(rda, “x.rds”)
       return(rda)
      }} else if (is.null(input$filepath)) {return()}

     if (is.null(input$filepath)) {return()}
     if (!is.null(input$filepath)) {
    if ((input$dataset=='sas7bdat')) {
       filepath2 <- input$filepath
       filepath3 <- filepath2$datapath
       data <- haven::read_sas(filepath3)
       return(data)
    }} else if (is.null(input$filepath)) {return()}

   })
   
   output$table2 <- renderTable({
     if (is.null(input$filepath)) {return()}
     else {
             table2() }
   })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems like the reference is still pointing to the other locator string (address) when you click the button, thus it throws the message. You could just silent error messages, but that kind of defies good programming. Ask the button to deselect the current table address upon clicking  the radio select or create a default string for each of the types of file such that it is looking at the appropriate file time upon selection.

Comment: thank you for your response. any thoughts on how i can silent the error or deselect the current table address

Comment: My first choice would be to change the logic in the button to silence the error. (some `ifelse(condition, outcome, otheroutcome)` work) because letting errors pass silently is problematic, especially when they effect the output data.

Short of that:`ags$style(type="text/css",
  ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
  ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
)`

Comment: Thank you @sconfluentus, it worked, used something as below in the mainpanel()

      tags$style(type="text/css",
                 ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                 ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
      )